# input of text area compared with text in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, textarea

I tried the following code to compare strings from div element and that from textarea element. Though I gave correct input in textarea, the code only executes 'else' statement. Please help me with this code.

```
function matchIt() {
    var inputstr = (document.getElementById("answerarea")).toString();//textarea element
    var displaystr = (document.getElementById("text")).toString();//div element
    var res = inputstr.localeCompare(displaystr);

    if(res==0)
    {
        alert("you won");
    }  
    else
    {
         alert("you loose");
    }
}
```

I tried with

- `if(res===0)`
- `(this.(document.getElementById("text"))).toString();` not giving the output.

Also when i tried the string with same type of elements like **h1** or **p** it gives correct output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the value of a `textarea`, you have to use `.value` (which is already a string), and to access the text content of a `div`, you should use the `.textContent` property.

```
var inputstr = document.getElementById("answerarea").value; //textarea element
var displaystr = document.getElementById("text").textContent; //div element
```

No need to convert to strings - they're already strings.

Also, rather than using `localeCompare` to check if strings are equal, just use `===`:

```js
var inputstr = document.getElementById("answerarea").value;
var displaystr = document.getElementById("text").textContent; 
console.log(inputstr === displaystr);
```

```html
<textarea id="answerarea" value="foo">foo</textarea>
<div id="text">foo</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance. I tried it with your solution and it is just working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get values from elements. Try `value` property for `textarea` and `textContent` for `div`.

Change

```
var inputstr =(document.getElementById("answerarea")).toString();//textarea element
var displaystr = (document.getElementById("text")).toString();//div element
```

To

```
var inputstr = document.getElementById("answerarea").value;//textarea element
var displaystr = document.getElementById("text").textContent;//div element
```